# Grid view custom paging with enough datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

In my asp.net 4.0 web application ,i need to fill a grid with 10 records in each page with only that corresponding 10 records as datasource.But i have lot of pages with data.Also need linq query for retriving data (Entity Framework is using)
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is link of article which does the same thing, hope this will help

[**LINQ TO SQL GridView (Enhanced Gridview)**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/08/linq-to-sql-gridview-enhanced-gridview.html)

Grid view control has the following features:

- Linq 2 SQL support
- Custom paging using Linq 2 SQL
- Display sorting direction
- Dropdown in the pager to adjust the number of records in a page

Comment: But i am using Entity framework with linq instead of linq to sql

Comment: @ROBIN - just replace layer of linq to sql with the enity framwork might resolve the issuee you ahve...